# C++ Vector initial capacity

Tags: c++, vector

I have some code which uses thousands of vectors each vector has only 4 entries, So I want to set the initial size of each vector to 4 so that I can optimize memory usage by not reserving unused memory.

I tried reserve method:

```
vector<Foo> bar;
bar.reserve(10);
```

but seems it expands and doesn't shrink, seems there also no constructor that creates a vector with a specified capacity.

**Also 2 bonus questions:**

What's the default initial capacity

Can I create a vector with a specific capacity?

Comment: If you want it at 4, why didn't you set it at 4?

Comment: How do you know that "it expands and doesn't shrink"?

Comment: if you want it to shrink, use `shrink_to_fit()`

Comment: There is indeed no constructor that takes an initial capacity. I've often bemoaned that. Maybe one day.

Comment: Am I the only one around here who doesn't understand what's wrong with `vector<Foo> bar; bar.reserve(4);`?

Comment: @Alex reserve will expand the current vector to capacity 4 if it was less than 4 otherwise it will not shrink the vector

Comment: @RedAlert Your answer is the closest to what I need thanks;

Comment: @mmohab: If that's what you need, then your question is certainly not worded to indicate it. If you want to shrink the vector's capacity, why are you talking about initializing it?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley because I know the size in advance so I have 2 options initialize it with initial capacity or shrink it later, I prefer the first approach

Comment: @mmohab: The default initial capacity is unspecified, but in every stdlib I know of the default is zero.  After that, if you add N, they'll allocate room for N, unless N=1, then they allocate for "several" (but I don't know what several is here)

Comment: Huh, apperently "several" is 1 for visual studio: http://rextester.com/INQ98845

Comment: @mmohab if you initialize the capacity to 4 and you never exceed it, you don't need to shrink the vector. If you've allocated more than needed the only sure way to free the reserved capacity is to copy the vector into a new vector which you've initialized with `reserve(4)` and then delete the old vector. `shrink_to_fit` is not guaranteed to actually shrink the reserved capacity of the vector.

Comment: @mmohab: Say that you do prefer the first approach (set the capacity upfront, don't shrink), now imagine you do so. How would the fact that `reserve()` does not shrink affect you at all, considering that you did set the capacity to the correct value? I am getting mixed signals in the question and comments. Take the time to think what you are asking, and note that `shrink_to_fit` is a *request*, not a *command*. A perfectly valid (standard) implementation of that function is to not do anything at all.

Comment: Come to think of it, the question would make a lot of sense if you consider the possibility than the initial capacity of a vector is more than 4 by default. So let me just say that although there is no guarantee, all well-known implementations of the standard library use 0 as the initial capacity and you can use `vector<Foo> bar; bar.reserve(4);` safely.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The capacity of a vector cannot be controlled by the constructors - there is no applicable overload.

The C++ standard doesn't give any guarantee about the capacity of a default-constructed vector `vector<Foo> bar;`. However all well-known implementations use 0 as the default capacity. This is something you *can* rely on, as allocating memory at that point just doesn't make sense.

So I believe the answer to your question is: just use

```
vector<Foo> bar;
bar.reserve(4);
```

Answer (score 18):

> each vector has only 4 entries

Then you're probably better off with a `std::array<Foo, 4>` instead.

And in case you need 4 elements because you want a *mathematical* vector, I suggest a struct:

```
struct Vector
{
    Foo x, y, z, w;
};
```

Comment: In other words, you need a C++11 compiler. Use GCC 4.9 if you don't have it.

Comment: actually that it not what i need, the vector size may change to other value 5 for example, but all the lists have the same size

Comment: So why did you say that each has four entries?  Now you're saying that they start with zero and can go over four?

Comment: @mmohab: Do you know this length at compile time?