# Set *both* elements and initial capacity of std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I've read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23415582/3719101) that the initial capacity of a `std::vector` couldn't be controlled by its constructor. The best way to set it, if you know its size will be constant at runtime, seems then to be:

```
const int size;
std::vector<T> v;
v.reserve(size);
```

But, since `T` is a big class, I'm happy to use the initialization argument of the constructor `std::vector<T> v(size, T());`. What is then the best way to allocate only the memory I need without having to manually iterate over the elements to initialize them?

```
std::vector<T> v;
v.reserve(size);
for(T t : v) t = T();    // `has to call T::operator= (that may not even be defined)
```

or

```
std::vector<T> v(size, T());  // may allocate more memory than I need..
v.shrink_to_fit();            // ..then deallocate it immediately (pointless)
```

What would be the closest to my ideal:

```
std::vector<T> v(size, T(), /*capacity =*/ size);
```

---

[EDIT]: It turns out from your answers that what I need more exactly is `v` to be filled with `size` instances of `T`, each build with `T`'s default constructor, and not copied. How can I do since I can't use an initializer list when `size` isn't known at compile time?

---

Bonus: By the way, why is there no way choosing the initial capacity of a vector?

Comment: If you need an exact and constant sized array, use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: @RetiredNinja: I can't, for as I said the size is known at runtime.

Comment: Ah, I missed that, sorry.

Comment: With `std::vector<T> v; v.reserve(size); for(T t : v) t = T();` the loop is useless as `v` is empty. (and anyway you would modify a copy of `v` content).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear how you want all the elements constructed.  Let's say you want the vector to have `n` elements and capacity `desired_capacity`, which may be equal to `n`.

If you want `n` elements identical, try this:

```
std::vector<T> v(n, t);  // creates n copies of the value t.
v.reserve(desired_capacity);
```

If you don't want to specify an initial value, you can omit that:

```
std::vector<T> v(n);     // creates n copies of T, default constructed.
v.reserve(desired_capacity);
```

If you have a certain number of elements you want to specify individually, try an initializer list.

```
std::vector({t1, t2, ..., tn});  // initializer list
v.reserve(desired_capacity);
```

The list of possibilities goes on; for more, see the [`vector::vector` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).  Using "in-place" construction means you can populate a vector with types that are not copy-constructible.

Another option, to fill a vector with non-copyable types, is to use emplace_back repeatedly:

```
std::vector<T> v;
v.reserve(n); 
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
   v.emplace_back(x, y, z);  // Construct T(x, y, z) in-place
}
```

One note about your original question: your for loop contains an error:

```
for(T t : v) t = T();    
// almost certainly want for (T& t : v) ...
// in order to get references to modify vector elements.
```

Comment: Hey, I think your answer, even further from the very `std::vector::capacity` problem of this topic, turns out to be closer from my actual problem. What I exactly need is, as you said, to "populate the vector with types that are not copy-constructible". That is: calling the default constructor `size` times. But I can't use an initializer list because `size` is unknown at compile time, what should I do then?

Comment: You can use the middle option, which creates values in place (no copying), if you want default construction.  Otherwise, you can create an empty vector, then use [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) an appropriate number of times.

Comment: By calling reserve on a non empty vector, you may move construct the initial value in the new *buffer*.

Answer (score 5):

Bonus first:

> Bonus: By the way, why is there no way choosing the initial capacity of a vector?

Because the designers of the class never considered it important enough to include.

---

I know of no implementation where after:

```
std::vector<T> v(size, T());
```

the following assert does not hold:

```
assert(v.capacity() == size);
```

It isn't guaranteed by the standard to hold.  But it does appear to be the de-facto standard.

One can not however transfer this bit of lore to `std::string`.

---

**If** you want to positively require that `capacity() == size()` after construction, you could use `shrink_to_fit()`.  That being said, `shrink_to_fit()` isn't guaranteed by the standard to work, and if it does do anything at all, it will *temporarily* double your memory requirements.  Such use might look like:

```
std::vector<T> v(size, T());
if (v.capacity() > v.size())
    v.shrink_to_fit(); // If executed and successful, this will allocate a new buffer
if (v.capacity() > v.size())
    // now what?
```

---

Use of `reserve()` is no more effective.  After `reserve()`, `capacity()` is **greater** or equal to the argument of `reserve` if reallocation happens; and equal to the previous value of `capacity()` otherwise.

Comment: Great! Should I then just be confident? Or use `v.shrink_to_fit()` just to be clear and it'll execute to nothing anyway?

Comment: PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE DO NOT USE `shrink_to_fit`. Ever.

Comment: @Massa: Okay, `v.reserve(size)` then. Will it then execute to nothing? And please please please tell us why! ^ ^

Comment: Yes, `v.reserve(x)` will not resize the vector if `x < v.capacity()`. And that is a good thing, because there is no functional in-place reallocation in the C++ standard; `std::vector` changing sizes implies `v.size()` copies...

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Okay, let's just trust the implementation then. :) Thank you!

Comment: @Massa:  My point was that `reserve()` is allowed to over-allocate.  Though in practice I know of no implementation that does.

Comment: @HowardHinnant and my point was: if it over-allocated, it's ok. You probably can afford a little "slack" RAM wasted, the alternative is almost always more expensive: _another_ allocation and O(N) moves (or worse, copies)....

Answer (score 1):

The vector constructors which specify the initial size all have to iterate to initialize the elements anyway. Even if you don't have code that explicitly iterates to initialize elements, that is what is happening inside the vector constructor.  So I don't see the problem with doing:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::vector<T> create_vector_with_capacity(size_t size, size_t capacity, Args... args)
{
    std::vector<T> v;
    v.reserve(capacity);

    for (size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i)
        v.emplace_back( args... );

    return v;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec = create_vector_with_capacity<std::string>(5, 20, "foo");
```

`std::vector`'s move semantics ensure that, even if copy-elision is disabled and `T` is not movable, the vector is not copied even though it is returned by value.

This version constructs each element in-place using `args` (or default constructor if you didn't provide any args); alternatively you could replace `Args... args` and `emplace_back` with `T&& t = T()` and `push_back`, which would copy-construct all elements from one (possibly temporary) that you pass in.

**Note:** Actually the standard does not absolutely guarantee that moving a vector retains its capacity (not that I'm aware of anyway); if your implementation doesn't do this , or if you really want to guarantee capacity retention, then instead of returning `v`, make it be a parameter passed by reference that the caller has to supply an empty vector for.

Answer (score 1):

You may do:

```
std::vector<T> v;
v.reserve(size); // don't construct any T. v.size() == 0.
v.resize(size);  // do construct T.
```

Comment: nice! would it *copy-construct* or *default-construct* each T? What if the constructor needs arguments?

Comment: In C++03, copy construct. In C++11, default construct.

Comment: If `T` requires arguments, you may do `v.resize(size, T(args));` (copy-construct).

Answer (score -1):

you can build vector with capacity and initial value,

```
std::vector<std::string> vs(5, "abc");
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> x(6, std::pair<int,int>(1, 2));
```

Comment: I think you're mixing up *size* with *capacity*