# C++ access vector beyond size() and under capacity()

Tags: c++, vector

Is it safe to access vector's `data()[i]` for indices `i` beyond vector's `size()` and under vector's `capacity()`?

Here is my reasoning:

a) According the [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/), `capacity()` is "the size of the storage space currently allocated for the vector" which makes me think that the answer to my question is `YES`, but then

b) Using `reserve()` and access `data` beyond vector's `size()` should be safe because according to [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/), `reserve()` "causes the container to reallocate its storage increasing its capacity to n", but then

c) [Stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972443/use-stdvectordata-after-reserve) contradicts the statement `b)` above

So I'm puzzled and looking for the answer.

Comment: Depends on your definition of safe. Program probably won't crash, but the results are undefined.

Comment: It also depends on the type of access. For example, calling an in-place constructor may be safe but calling `operator=` may not be.

Comment: Many debugging runtime libraries will stop your program dead in its tracks with an `assert` if you go beyond `size()`.  For example, the Visual C++ debug runtime will halt your program.

Comment: Between index 0 and `size()` you have valid data, between index `size()` and `capacity()` you only have valid memory. At best you can initialize the valid memory but still vector will not manage it in any meaningful way. There are some details about reasons to circunvent the vector interface here: https://lemire.me/blog/2012/06/20/do-not-waste-time-with-stl-vectors/

Comment: Note: cplusplus.com tends to favour easy reading for beginners over accuracy. This is great until you hit  a problem that requires literal correctness. At that point [prefer cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/), and if that's not good enough, [go to the C++ Standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/). Note that as you get into deeper and more correct documentation, it gets much harder to understand without a strong backing knowledge (and sometimes a law degree).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't valid to access `data()[n]` if `n >= size()`.  Per [[vector.data]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/vector.data) `std::vector::data`

> Returns: A pointer such that `[data(), data() + size())` is a valid range. For a non-empty vector, `data() == addressof(front())`.

So it is only valid to access `data` with a value in the range of `[0, size())`.

---

Generally then memory between `data() + size() - 1` and `data + capacity()` is uninitialized.  If you read from that uninitialized memory that is undefined behavior.  If you have an object that has non trivial initialization then you can't even assign a value to it since there isn't an object actually in that spot, just the space for one.  You could probably get away with doing things in the uninitialized range, but your violating the contract with `std::vector` and it might get angry if you do ;)

Comment: And after `size()` things get fun. The library implementation could include code that checks for out of bounds access and halts your program with an error message. It could do nothing and let the program consume unknown  data values. It could play La Macarena.

Comment: The inference is not true. The statement does not say what else is valid. The comment by @DavidSchwartz is more to the point.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. The [vector.capacity](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/vector.capacity) is less ambiguous there: `The total number of elements that the vector can hold without requiring reallocation`. Which does not imply the fact that `data()` returns a pointer to the region of size `capacity`

Comment: @user4581301 That reminds me to someday make a C++ implementation which would play La Macarena + rendering Rick Ashleys picture in every frame buffer it can find, whenever UB is invoked or implementation defined behaviour allows it.

Answer (score 3):

No it is **not safe** because §23.3.6.4 of ISO/IEC 14882:2014 states

> vector data ... Returns: A pointer such that [data(),data() + size()) is a valid range.

So by the standard everything beyond `size()` is not defined, meaning the so called *undefined behaviour*, which as everybody will confirm, is something very unsafe.

To be fair, usually nothing bad would happen, but this is a very weak usually, which means, another compiler, operating system, and boom things happen, and you can not tell that. And to be also complete, there are several implementations where this will crash, I think for example when you compile with address sanitisation. Just don't do it.

Comment: Regarding *everybody will confirm*, I remember ads as a child stating that 9 out of 10 dentists agree that brushing your teeth was good. I always wondered what was up with that tenth dentist.